# Display new row inserted after ajax callback

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here there is my code which insert a row in ajax, it's working perfectly.

I need to display the new row that the user inserted inside my select multiple without reload the page but i don't know how to do ..

Thank you for you help

**Ajax call :**

```
$('#insertForm').on('click', function(){
    var form_user = $('input[name=form_user]').val();
    var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();
    var form_organisme = $('input[name=form_organisme]').val();
    var form_date = $('input[name=form_date]').val();
    var form_benefice = $('textarea[name=form_benefice]').val();
    var form_dispositif = $('#form_dispositif').val();
    var form_entpro_ActionAutre = $('input[name=entpro_ActionAutre]').val();

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "lib/function.php?insertForm="+insertForm+"&form_user="+form_user+"&form_intitule="+form_intitule+"&form_organisme="+form_organisme+"&form_date="+form_date+"&form_benefice="+form_benefice+"&form_dispositif="+form_dispositif+"&form_entpro_ActionAutre="+form_entpro_ActionAutre,
  dataType : "html",
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
      },
  success:function(data){
  }
});
});
```

**My select multiple in function.php :**

```
$displayFormation = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM FORMATION WHERE form_id_user = :idSalarie ORDER BY form_date DESC');
$displayFormation->bindParam(':idSalarie', $_POST['idSalarie']);
$displayFormation->execute();

$data['formation'] .='
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nomSalarie" class="col-sm-1 control-label" id="nameSelect">Formations</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
            <select name="listeFormation[]" id="listeFormation" class="form-control" multiple>';
                while($ligne = $displayFormation->fetch()){
                    $data['formation'] .='<option value="'. $ligne['form_id'].'">'.$ligne['form_intitule']. " [" . $ligne['form_organisme'] . "]". " [Année : " . dateAnglaisVersFrancaisAnnee($ligne['form_date']) . "]" . " [Bénéfices : " . $ligne['form_benefice'] . "]" . " [Dispositif : " . $ligne['form_dispositif'] . "]".'</option>';
                }
               $data['formation'] .='
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>';
```

Comment: What is the specific question or problem? We don't know what needs to go into the `<select>`

Comment: i have updated my post and display the query that power the select

Comment: In success callback you need to create an `<option>` tag and append it to `<select>`

Comment: `$('#listeFormation').append('<option>'+  +'</option>'); ` but what i have to write between the '+' ?

Comment: whatever values you need from form data. Also need `value="'++"`

Comment: but this method not reload my select, it's rewrite an option in select, that is not the same thing ..

Comment: Goes back to my first comment. Question is not clear. Do you want to replace the whole select with the code from php as html response in ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103112/discussion-between-lucas-frugier-and-charlietfl).

Comment: i opened the chat with you

Comment: Without any example of what `data` will return, it's hard to know how to handle your `success` function. Please provide an example of the `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make some guesses and also some suggestions. Without knowing what your resulting data is going to be, it's hard to answer fully.

My working example and tests: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/053q24dh/

Here is the JQuery I would advise:

```
$('#insertForm').on('click', function() {
  var form_user = $('input[name=form_user]').val();
  var form_intitule = $('input[name=form_intitule]').val();
  var form_organisme = $('input[name=form_organisme]').val();
  var form_date = $('input[name=form_date]').val();
  var form_benefice = $('textarea[name=form_benefice]').val();
  var form_dispositif = $('#form_dispositif').val();
  var form_entpro_ActionAutre = $('input[name=entpro_ActionAutre]').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "lib/function.php",
    data: {
      "insertForm": insertForm,
      "form_user": form_user,
      "form_intitule": form_intitule,
      "form_organisme": form_organisme,
      "form_date": form_date,
      "form_benefice": form_benefice,
      "form_dispositif": form_dispositif,
      "form_entpro_ActionAutre": form_entpro_ActionAutre,
    },
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // Asumming the page returns the following HTML, or something similar:
      // <option value="9">Title [Organize] [Année : 02/02/16] [Bénéfices : 1] [Dispositif : 1]</option>
      $("#listeFormation").append(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Again, this assumes that the HTML that is being returned to `data` is a single `option` tag to be appended to the `select` object. It looks like your PHP in the Post is looking for `POST` and your ajax is making a `GET`, so I am assuming they are different PHP Scripts. If they are not, you need to make sure the PHP knows how to respond properly and is not sending back too much data.

Also, I noticed that `insertForm` is not defined in this code snippet. If it's defined globally, that's fine, otherwise you need to define it within the scope of this function.

Comment: but this method not reload my select, it's write an option in the select, that is not the same thing.. if you press F5 the option will be removed. the form execute an 'insert into' query and after the query is done i need to display the new row that the user submitted inside the select

Comment: Why would the user hit F5? And if they did, wouldn't your PHP Update the SQL Table and thus, when the data is collected on refresh, the new Select would have all the content?